# An underdetermined system derived for rotated coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, classical-mechanics

Consider two orthogonal coordinate systems $x_A y_A z_A$ and $x_B y_B z_B$ sharing the same origin. Denote by $\boldsymbol i_A$, $\boldsymbol j_A$, $\boldsymbol k_A$ the set of basis vectors, and assume that $\boldsymbol k_B$ is given in $x_A y_A z_A$. Using directional cosines expansion, I derive the system
$$
\begin{cases} \boldsymbol i_B = c_{xx} \boldsymbol i_A + c_{xy}  \boldsymbol j_A + c_{xz} \boldsymbol k_A \\ \boldsymbol j_B = c_{yx} \boldsymbol i_A + c_{yy} \boldsymbol j_A + c_{yz} \boldsymbol k_A \\ c_{zx} c_{xx} + c_{zy} c_{xy} + c_{zz} c_{xz} = 0 \\ c_{zx} c_{yx} + c_{zy} c_{yy} + c_{zz} c_{yz} = 0 \\ c_{xx}^2 + c_{xy}^2 + c_{xz}^2 = 1 \\ c_{yx}^2 + c_{yy}^2 + c_{yz}^2 = 1 \end{cases}
$$
which is underdetermined, so I need 2 additional constraints.

It is given that each line $AB$ in $x_A y_A z_A$ that is parallel to the $z_A$ axis, is rotated to a line CD in $x_B y_B z_B$, which is parallel to the $z_B$ axis. Moreover, AB and CD intersect.

**How to express these constraints in terms of directional cosines? Are there constraints missing from the derived system?**

Thank you for your attention and time.

**Edit 1**

I am not sure, but I think that because of orthogonality of $z_B$ to $x_B y_B$ and $z_A$ to $x_A y_A$, the angle between $x_A$ and $x_B$ is equal to the angle between $y_A$ and $y_B$, so that $c_{xx} = c_{yy}$. **This is wrong!**

**Edit 2**
We also need to add
$$
\boldsymbol i_B \cdot \boldsymbol j_B = c_{xx} c_{yx} + c_{xy} c_{yy} + c_{xz} c_{yz} = 0
$$
to the system. So, now we have 7 equations for 8 unknowns:
$$
\begin{cases} \boldsymbol i_B = c_{xx} \boldsymbol i_A + c_{xy}  \boldsymbol j_A + c_{xz} \boldsymbol k_A \\ \boldsymbol j_B = c_{yx} \boldsymbol i_A + c_{yy} \boldsymbol j_A + c_{yz} \boldsymbol k_A \\ c_{zx} c_{xx} + c_{zy} c_{xy} + c_{zz} c_{xz} = 0 \\ c_{zx} c_{yx} + c_{zy} c_{yy} + c_{zz} c_{yz} = 0 \\ c_{xx} c_{yx} + c_{xy} c_{yy} + c_{xz} c_{yz} = 0 \\ c_{xx}^2 + c_{xy}^2 + c_{xz}^2 = 1 \\ c_{yx}^2 + c_{yy}^2 + c_{yz}^2 = 1 \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Never used that method before, or it has a different name in my language... But any reason why you didn't include
$\mathbf i_b.\mathbf j_B=0$ and
$\|\mathbf k_B\|^2=1$ ?

Comment: Actually, I would welcome any other approach.

I really did not think about $\boldsymbol i_B \cdot \boldsymbol j_B = 0$. Thanks! On the other hand, $\boldsymbol k_B$ is given, so no need to add your second constraint to the system.

What do you think about $c_{xx} = c_{yy}$?

Comment: I think it'd be a bit simpler to parameterize the rotation, and express $\mathbf i_B,\mathbf j_B$ with respect to those parameters... I'll have a quick look.
Regarding "$c_{xx}=c_{yy}$", I think it's wrong, but I don't have a simple example/explanation to give you right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your two coordinate systems are right-handed, there exists a rotation $r_{L,\theta}$ with axis $L$ through the origin, and angle $\theta$,
such that
\begin{align}
\mathbf i_B &= r_{L,\theta}(\mathbf i_A)\\
\mathbf j_B &= r_{L,\theta}(\mathbf j_A)\\
\mathbf k_B &= r_{L,\theta}(\mathbf k_A)
\end{align}
Expressing the rotation for an arbitrary point is a little annoying in general, but we here have the additional constraint that if you rotate a line parallel to $\mathbf k_A$, its image by $r_{L,\theta}$ will always intersect the original line. I don't feel like doing it right now, but you can show that this condition implies that $L$ must be orthogonal to $\mathbf k_A$.

In other words, consider $\mathbf u$ a direction vector of $L$, and let $\mathbf v$ such that $\mathbf u,\mathbf v,\mathbf k_A$ is a (right-handed) orthonormal basis. There exists
$\varphi\in\mathbb R$ such that
\begin{align}
\mathbf u &~=~&  \cos(\varphi) \mathbf i_A& +\sin(\varphi)\mathbf j_A\\
\mathbf v &~=~& -\sin(\varphi) \mathbf i_A& +\cos(\varphi)\mathbf j_A\\
\mathbf i_A &~=~& \cos(\varphi)\mathbf u& -\sin(\varphi)\mathbf v\\
\mathbf j_A &~=~& \sin(\varphi)\mathbf u& +\cos(\varphi)\mathbf v
\end{align}

Now you get
\begin{cases}
\mathbf i_B &=& r_{L,\theta}(\mathbf i_A) &=& \cos(\varphi)\mathbf u-\sin(\varphi)\Big( \cos(\theta)\mathbf v+\sin(\theta)\mathbf k_A \Big)\\
\mathbf j_B &=& r_{L,\theta}(\mathbf j_A) &=& \sin(\varphi)\mathbf u+\cos(\varphi)\Big( \cos(\theta)\mathbf v+\sin(\theta)\mathbf k_A \Big)\\
\mathbf k_B &=& r_{L,\theta}(\mathbf k_A) &=& -\sin(\theta)\mathbf v+\cos(\theta)\mathbf k_A
\end{cases}
If you plug in the expressions of $\mathbf u,\mathbf v$ in the equation above, you'll obtain an expression of $\mathbf i_B,\mathbf j_B,\mathbf k_B$ in terms of $\mathbf i_A,\mathbf j_A,\mathbf k_A,\varphi$ and $\theta$. Basically if you can determine $\varphi$ and $\theta$, you'll get $\mathbf i_B$ and $\mathbf j_B$. In particular
$$
\mathbf k_B = \sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi)\mathbf i_A -\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi)\mathbf j_A +\cos(\theta)\mathbf k_A 
=c_{zx}\mathbf i_A+c_{zy}\mathbf j_A+c_{zz}\mathbf k_A
$$
so you can  fairly easily obtain $\varphi$ and $\theta$ in the *general case*.

Note that your problem statement ensures that we are in the general case, because the thing on the lines parallel to $\mathbf k_A$ guarantees that $\sin(\theta)\neq 0$, meaning that you can always find $\varphi$, from which you can always deduce $\theta$, and everything else from there.
I was too lazy to prove the thing on lines parallel to $\mathbf k_A$ then, and I'm still too lazy now. If you really need it and can't figure it out, ping me sometimes next week and I'll have a look.

---

EDIT: Assuming I didn't mess up somewhere above, you also get
$$
c_{xx}=\cos(\varphi)^2+\sin(\varphi)^2\cos(\theta)
$$
and
$$
c_{yy} = \sin(\varphi)^2+\cos(\varphi)^2\cos(\theta)
$$
so in general $c_{xx}\neq c_{yy}$.

Comment: It is clear that $c_{xx} \neq c_{yy}$. Let me check if I understand your formulas.

Comment: I found:
$$
\sin \theta \sin \varphi = \boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol i_A,
$$
$$
-\sin \theta \cos \varphi = \boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol j_A,
$$
$$
\cos \theta = \boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol k_A.
$$
Thus,
$$
\sin \theta = \pm \sqrt{1 - (\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol k_A)^2},
$$
$$
\sin \varphi = \frac{\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol i_A}{\sin \theta} = \pm \frac{\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol i_A}{\sqrt{1 - (\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol k_A)^2}},
$$

Comment: $$
\cos \varphi = - \frac{\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol j_A}{\sin \theta} = \mp \frac{\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol j_A}{\sqrt{1 - (\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol k_A)^2}}.
$$

Comment: Check,
$$
\cos \varphi = \pm \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \varphi} = \pm \sqrt{1 - \frac{(\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol i_A)^2}{1 - (\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol k_A)^2}} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 - (\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol k_A)^2 - (\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol i_A)^2}{1 - (\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol k_A)^2}}
$$
Is it the same as
$$
\mp \frac{\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol j_A}{\sqrt{1 - (\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol k_A)^2}}
$$
?

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan : I'll be frank, I wouldn't have done it that way. Regarding your "check" question, $$\|\mathbf k_B\|^2=(\mathbf k_B.\mathbf i_A)^2+(\mathbf k_B.\mathbf j_A)^2+(\mathbf k_B.\mathbf k_A)^2=1$$ so the absolute values are equal. If there's a real problem, it's that if you use $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$ you cannot know how the sign behaves wrt to the other equations. Because of sign issues, the actual answer to your "check" is "yes" iff "$\pm\lvert\mathbf k_B.\mathbf j_A\rvert=\mp\mathbf k_B.\mathbf j_A$", otherwise "no". That condition can be re-stated as $\mathbf k_B.\mathbf j_A\le 0$.

Comment: I'd personally rather notice that without loss of generality, you can suppose $-\frac\pi2<\varphi<\frac\pi2$ thus $$\varphi=\text{atan}\left(\frac{\mathbf k_B.\mathbf i_A}{\mathbf k_B.\mathbf j_A}\right)$$ From $\varphi$ you get both $\cos(\varphi)$ and $\sin(\varphi)$ so you obtain $\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: I am a bit lost in the issue with the sign. Assume that any vector $\boldsymbol a$ in $z_A y_A$ that has the same direction as $k_A$, is transformed into $\boldsymbol b$ in the $z_B y_B$ plane and has the same direction as $\boldsymbol k_B$. Moreover, $\boldsymbol a$ and $\boldsymbol b$ intersect. It means that $\boldsymbol k_B \cdot j_A \leq 0$, doesn't it?

Comment: Moreover, any vector $\boldsymbol c$ in $z_A x_A$ plane that has the same direction as $k_A$, is transformed into $\boldsymbol d$ in the $z_B x_B$ plane and has the same direction as $\boldsymbol k_B$. Again, $\boldsymbol c$ and $\boldsymbol d$ intersect. It means that $\boldsymbol k_B \cdot i_A \leq 0$, doesn't it?

Comment: Now I understand the sign issue, thanks.

Comment: The last question. In the expression for $\boldsymbol i_B$ I get $...−(\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol i_A) \boldsymbol k_A$, and for $\boldsymbol j_B$ I get $...−(\boldsymbol k_B \cdot \boldsymbol j_A) \boldsymbol k_A$. Why both are with "minus" sign?

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan It's just what the computation yields, that's nearly like asking why "$1+1=2$"... If you absolutely want to put some "meaning" behind that you should draw those vectors to understand the geometry of the problem, instead of just looking at equations. To put this in perspective, look at the simpler 2D case. I used $$\mathbf v=-\sin\theta\mathbf i_A+\cos\theta\mathbf j_A$$ but I could have written that out as $$\mathbf v=-(\mathbf u.\mathbf j_A)\mathbf i_A+(\mathbf u.\mathbf i_A)\mathbf j_A$$ Then why is it "$-(\mathbf u.\mathbf j_A)$" ? If you draw it for...

Comment: ... an angle $\theta$ between $0$ and $\frac\pi 2$, it'll come out as "obvious". Your question is basically the same but in 3D.

Comment: What makes me confused is that I obtain $\boldsymbol i_B \cdot \boldsymbol j_A = \boldsymbol j_B \cdot \boldsymbol i_A$. Is it really the case?

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan That's not what you wrote in your last comments, and that's not the case in general (there are some specific values of $\varphi,\theta$ for which the equality is true).

Comment: I reduce it from your formulas after expressing $\boldsymbol i_B$ and $\boldsymbol j_B$ in terms of $\boldsymbol i_A$, $\boldsymbol j_A$ and $\boldsymbol k_A$.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan You're right, I read your comment too quickly. Sorry about that. But my overall answer is still "yes, that's what the computation yields" and "try drawing it", except that 3D drawings are a bit annoying. If you really aren't confident, just verify that your solutions satisfy $\mathbf i_B,\mathbf j_B,\mathbf k_B$ is an orthonormal basis.